# Apple Photos Shared Albums on OS X are not updating - tried restarting Photos Agent but no luck

Tags: macos, icloud, photos

I have exactly the same problem as this - [Apple Photos Shared Albums on OS X are not updating](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/207694/apple-photos-shared-albums-on-os-x-are-not-updating) - but the answer doesn't work for me.  I was wondering if there's any way to troubleshoot, e.g. looking at logs?

The album is definitely shared (other people can see it) but one particular Mac cannot see the new photos.  Before I restart the Mac I was hoping for a way to investigate without forcing the full reset.

Comment: stevec did you find a solution for your problem?

Comment: No - in the end I think I restarted the Mac and that resolved the problem, but it would definitely be preferable to have an alternative way to troubleshoot . . . .